# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '­' (T_STRING) in products\app\code\local\Sahara\Recentproducts\Block\Recentproducts.php on line 8

Tags: meta-tags

> D:\xampp\htdocs\products\app\code\local\Sahara\Recentproducts\etc\config.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sahara_Recentproducts>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Sahara_Recentproducts>
  </modules>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
      <recentproducts>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Sahara_Recentproducts</module>
          <frontName>recentproducts</frontName>
        </args>
      </recentproducts>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
        <recentproducts>
        <file>sahara_recentproducts.xml</file>
        </recentproducts>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<global>
<resources>
      <recentproducts_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>sahara_recentproducts</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </recentproducts_setup>
      <recentproducts_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </recentproducts_write>
      <recentproducts_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </recentproducts_read>
    </resources>
<models>
<recentproducts>
<class>Sahara_Recentproducts_Model</class>
</recentproducts>
</models>

<blocks>
<recentproducts>
<class>Sahara_Recentproducts_Block</class>
</recentproducts>
</blocks>
<helpers>

<recentproducts>
<class>Sahara_Recentproducts_Helper</class>
</recentproducts>
</helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

> D:\xampp\htdocs\products\app\code\local\Sahara\Recentproducts\controllers\ProductsController.php

```
<?php

class Sahara_Recentproducts_ProductsController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

   /**
   * Index action
   *
   * @access public

   * @return void
   */

   public function indexAction() {


   $this->loadLayout();


   $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Recent Products'));
   $this->renderLayout();

   }

   /**

    * Done it again
    *
    * @access public
    * @return void
    */

}

?>
```

> D:\xampp\htdocs\products\app\code\local\Sahara\Recentproducts\Model\Recentproducts.php

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Envato/Recentproducts/Model/Recentproducts.php
class Sahara_Recentproducts_Model_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

 public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('recentproducts/recentproducts');
       // parent::_construct();
    }
 public function getRecentproducts()
 {
     $products= Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                ->getCollection();
     return $products;
 }
}
```

> D:\xampp\htdocs\products\app\code\local\Sahara\Recentproducts\Block\Recentproducts.php (block class)

```
<?php
 class Sahara_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
public function getRecentproducts()
{

 $products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")­>getRecentproducts();
 return $products;
}

}
```

D:\xampp\htdocs\products\app\design\frontend\default\theme692\layout\sahara_recentproducts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<layout version="0.1.0">

<recentproducts_products_index>
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle"><title>Products</title></action>          
     </reference>
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="recentproducts/recentproducts" name="recentproducts_recentproducts" template="recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml"/>
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</recentproducts_products_index>

</layout>
```

> D:\xampp\htdocs\products\app\design\frontend\default\theme692\template\recentproducts

```
<?php
// app/design/frontend/default/default/template/recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml
$products = $this­>getRecentproducts();
//echo get_class_methods(get_class($this));
?>

<div id="product_list">
  <h1>Recent Products</h1>
  <?php if (is_array($products) && count($products)) { ?>
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a typo ...

Replace:

```
$products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")­>getRecentproducts();
```

With:

```
$products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")->getRecentproducts();
```

(the `-` before `>getRecentproducts()` seems to be some special char(?) )

Comment: I fixed this problem but even same error is showing.

Comment: @hiteshbalpande can you please check your php code with: https://phpcodechecker.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some special character written inpplace of **-** where it should be **->** as given below

```
<?php
class Sahara_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
 public function getRecentproducts()
  {

 $products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")->getRecentproducts();
 return $products;
 }
}
```

Comment: Check source ... there is something like a dash, but it is something else :)